# jQuery.outerHeight doesn't work when element is hidden?

Tags: jquery, css, height

I'm trying to find out the outer height of a element (including padding) and it doesn't seem to work.

I always get 0. Is it because the element is hidden?

The element is contained inside a absolute-positioned element with "auto" height, but I don't think that should be a issue, because the element is relative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a hidden element has an outer height,

```
<div id="aaa" style="visibility:hidden">aaa</div>
<div id="bbb" style="visibility:hidden"></div>

alert($("#aaa").outerHeight());// returns 20

alert($("#bbb").outerHeight()); //returns 0
```

please add your html code for a more complete answer

Comment: I'm guessing that by hidden he means "display:none", which of course would return a height of 0.

Answer (score 1):

An element with hidden with a `display: none;` does not register height or width, but an element with `visibility: hidden;` does, but it also must be attached to the `body` or one of its children elements.