# Issue getting the height of an element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the height of an element with jQuery, but for some reason it always returns `0`.

I load content using ajax in a container. This content is hidden by default (`display: none`). Before showing the content I need to retrieve the height of an element in the new content.

Which [should work](http://jsfiddle.net/vgTDr/).

My simplified code:

```
success: function(data) // this is the success callback of jquery's ajax call
{
  var content = $('#content');
  content.fadeOut('slow', function() {
    content.html(data.html);
    set_comments_height();
    content.fadeIn('slow');
  });
}

function set_comments_height()
{
  var content = $('#content');
  var info = $('.trackinfo .artwork-and-info', content);

  console.log(parseInt(info.outerHeight(true), 10));
}
```

You can see the issue on [my website](http://new.upcoming-djs.com) after clicking a track at the left side.

I might be missing something here, but I don't see why it doesn't return the correct height.

Comment: This doesn't work with hidden elements.

Comment: @Alfabravo how come it works in jsfiddle?

Comment: Wow. Looks like I got older hehehe. Yes, it works now. Try using a single selector like:

**$('#content > .trackinfo > .artwork-and-info').outerHeight(true);**

I tried with your site in console and it evaluates to 109.

Comment: @Alfabravo nopez doesn't work. Even when I just run the contents of the `set_comments_height()` function in the console it DOES work.

Comment: Well, check for some other error... in my case, sound.play raises an error (not a function). Maybe the script execution stops because of some other error.

Comment: @Alfabravo also when I output the `.html()`, just before I try to get the height, of the container is DOES contain the stuff.

Comment: @Alfabravo I don't get an error, prop you're just clicking too fast (player not yet loaded :) it's on my list :P).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`outerHeight()` will return 0 for elements with `display` property set to `none`. To counter this, in your AJAX's success handler, before setting the html, set the element's `opacity` to `0` and `display` to `block` (it still wont show up as opacity is 0). Once the html is set, call you set_comments_height() function followed by a css animation to bring it back to `opacity: 1`

i.e.

```
success: function(data) // this is the success callback of jquery's ajax call
{
  var content = $('#content');
  content.fadeOut('slow', function() {

    // opacity -> 0 and display -> block
    content.css({'opacity': 0, 'display': 'block'});

    content.html(data.html);
    set_comments_height();

    // instead of fadeIn, use CSS animation to bring it to opacity 1
    content.animate({'opacity': 1}, 'slow');

  });
}
```

Comment: But how come it works on jsfiddle? P.S. You are correct though. it does seem to return the correct height now.

Comment: Well, thats interesting. I've come across this very issue more than once and each time i had to resort to some hack (for ex like the one i pointed out), i wonder if jQuery's later versions have that fixed. Let me look this up further. I'll get back to you.

Comment: @PeeHaa Both jsFiddle and your site have jQ 1.7.1. That's odd

Comment: @Alfabravo - Not just the jQuery version. The doc types are exactly the same too. Still the difference! I have not been able to figure out why till now..

Comment: Looks like jsFiddle is to blame hehe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131995/jquery-outerheight-doesnt-work-when-element-is-hidden and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345784/jquery-get-height-of-hidden-element-in-jquery-1-4-2 ...